# Ruby accessing outer variables in nested function

Tags: ruby, nested, scope

I'm sure there's a simple answer for this; I just can't seem to find it. I made a nested function in Ruby, and I was having trouble accessing variables from the outer function inside the inner function:

```
def foo(x)
  def bar
    puts x
  end
  bar
  42
end

foo(5)
```

I get: `NameError: undefined local variable or method`x' for main:Object`

The analogous Python code works:

```
def foo(x):
  def bar():
    print x
  bar()
  return 42

foo(5)
```

So how do I do the same thing in Ruby?

Comment: An important (but subtle) distinction here is that def...end defines a method, not a function.  use lambda/proc to define functions and capture local variables in a closure, as tadman shows.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As far as I know, defining a named function within a function does not give you access to any local variables.

What you can do instead is use a Proc:

```
def foo(x)
  bar = lambda do
    puts x
  end
  bar.call
  42
end

foo(5)
```