# Can you access Ruby variables with outer scope inside of methods?

Tags: ruby, scope

I'm learning Ruby and practicing by writing a Caesar cipher. Here's my code so far:

```
print "Enter rotation: "
rotation = gets.chomp
print "Enter string to encrypt: "
string = gets.chomp

def encrypt
    keys = (' '..'z').to_a
    values = (' '..'z').to_a.rotate(rotation)
    hash = Hash[keys.zip(values)]
    chars = string.split('')
    encrypted_chars = chars.collect { |char| hash[char] }
    encryptd_string = encrypted_chars.join
end

puts "Encrypted string: " + encrypt
```

It's saying that I don't have access to the `rotation` variable inside of the `encrypt` method. `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'rotation' for main:Object`.

From what I understand, `rotation` is a local variable with outer scope, and should be accessible inside of the `encrypt` method. Obviously something is wrong with that reasoning, so could someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby accessing outer variables in nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016408/ruby-accessing-outer-variables-in-nested-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Ruby accessing outer variables in nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016408/ruby-accessing-outer-variables-in-nested-function).

You could make it an instance variable on the containing object by calling it `@rotation`, but why not just pass `string` and `rotation` into the `encrypt` method?

Comment: I could pass the parameters to the `encrypt` method, I was just looking for the simplest solution.

Comment: So what about this:

`def outer
  def inner
  end
end`

Could you access `outer`'s variables in `inner`?

Comment: No, you can’t; see the link I put in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour is that Local variables exist in a local scope and defining a method creates a new local scope for that method. Local varables are only visible in the current scope.

I was confused by this and found that relating the OP's question to one of nested methods only added confusion. But I've done a bit more research and discovered [this succinct question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779171/why-cant-i-access-a-local-variable-inside-a-method-in-ruby) and, in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10782889) that explains it clearly as well as demonstrating a way to define a method without creating a new scope.

(I'm just adding this answer for the benefit of others because my search for an answer led me to this question.)